# Why is low inductance important for stepper motors?

Tags: stepper-motor, inductance, stepper-driver

I’m building a CNC style device and am in the process of choosing the right stepper motors.

I read that it’s important to buy steppers with maximally 5mH of inductance.

Why exactly is that the case?

Is it because higher inductance means having to run them at higher voltage to achieve the rated holding torque?

In some forum I picked up this formula for stepper motor voltage:

```
Voltage = Sqrt(inductance) * 32
```

Is this formula correct? Where does “32” come from? So does that mean that a stepper rated with 3.0A and 5.6 mH phase inductance must be driven with 75 volts and chopper drivers set to 3A in order for it to perform optimally (yield the rated holding torque?)

Also,  inductance is sometimes written diffently in the sheets. Sometimes it’s “inductance/phase”, sometimes it’s “phase inductance”, but sometimes there are also two inductance ratings, one for “unipolar” and one for “bipolar."

Which is which and what rating does the above formula apply for?

Additional question:

Is there any way for me to compute the torque at a specific speed?

Comment: Torque X speed=power generated; power used=voltage X current (keeping phase in mind); power generated=power used X efficiency.  Can you approximate the efficiency of your motor choices at different speeds?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming torque is proportional to current, we can compute the current as

Current = (1/Inductance) * integral(voltage * time)

Thus MORE voltage for MORE TIME gives more torque.

And Less inductance gives more torque.

Comment: That makes sense but doesn't really answer my questions

Comment: How accurately do you wish to compute the torque, in the absence of precision mechanical and airgap modeling, and with no knowledge of the internal permanent-magnets' field strength?

Comment: I want a rule-of thumb formula that tells me: given a chopper driver rated for X Amps and Y Volts, what are the specs of the stepper motor that will yield best performance using this driver when run at the maximum amps, voltage the driver supports